Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*' or one of its dependencies
I have a C#(Business Logic) and .NET Core project. It was working fine on windows server 2012. I have updated the operating system to windows server 2022. Now I am facing this problem on all the projects where I am referencing Newtonsoft.json. Although on the projects level I checked the referenced Newtonsoft package version is 9.0.0.0.

"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
On some projects the error is coming as:  Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

in full framework projects it's quite tricky with multiple versions.. Check AssemblyRedirects in yout web.config, might help you.

Do you mean you have two project's one is using the 9.0.0 and another one is using the 13.0.0?
